# Why does checking for variable existence in jQuery callback cause a hard exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Note that `doesNotExist` intentionally does not exist, the alert is never shown, and instead we're left with an error in the browser's console. What's special about running this code in a jQuery callback that makes it fail so hard like this?

HTML:

```
<div>Shown! But we failed before the alert. Check your console...</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
$('div').fadeIn(100, function() {
    if (doesNotExist) {
        alert('Nope');
    }
    else {
        alert('Still nope');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrpowell3j/gnhoheze/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about running that code in a callback. It'll cause that exception no matter how it runs. Using an undeclared variable name in an expression is always an error (except with `typeof`).

To check whether a variable is defined, you can use

```
if (typeof doesNotExist === "undefined") {
  // it is undefined
}
```

Now that just tells you that it's either not defined at all, or that it has no value; either might be appropriate depending on the application.  If it's supposed to be a global, then:

```
if (!("doesNotExist" in window)) {
  // not defined
}
```

That checks for a property in the `window` object, which is where globals go (well, global `var` variables).

Comment: Right you are. I can't believe I haven't come across this before. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your are executing invalid javascript code. The callback do not matter in this case.

You must initialize your variable before using it or check if it exist using a different approach:

```
var variableName;
// execute your code.
```

-

```
//or checking if variable is defined.
if(typeof variableName !== 'undefined') {
   alert('nope');    
} else {
   alert('still nope');
}
```